# unable to use alias in Update statment in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, common-table-expression

I working of update query for with the help of CTEs. Actually I want to update a table records, on the basis of duplicate records I just want to update one one row among those duplicate rows. My code is mentioned below:

```
 with toupdate as (
  select c.*,
         count(*) over (partition by c.ConsumerReferenceNumber) as cnt,
         max(c.ID) over (partition by  c.ID) as onhand_value
  from [dbo].[tbl_NADRA_CPS] c
 )
 update [dbo].[tbl_NADRA_CPS]
 set StatusID = 38
 where cnt > 1;
```

I am unable to use 'cnt' in my update where clause.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Update your CTE, not the original table.

Comment: I got this. i have to give the same name of CTE as table name in update statement:

Comment: Thanks alot @HoneyBadger.

Comment: @HoneyBadger Can you kindly guide me will it update only one of the duplicate rows or both duplicate rows?

Comment: It will update both, change your count to a row_number to update only one.

Answer (score 2):

Because `cnt` is a field of your CTE, not of `[dbo].[tbl_NADRA_CPS]`

```
with toupdate as (
  select c.*,
         count(*) over (partition by c.ConsumerReferenceNumber) as cnt,
         max(c.ID) over (partition by  c.ID) as onhand_value
  from [dbo].[tbl_NADRA_CPS] c
 )
 update toupdate
 set StatusID = 38
 where cnt > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update *one* row among the duplicates, then your query will not do that.  Instead:

```
 with toupdate as (
       select c.*,
              count(*) over (partition by c.ConsumerReferenceNumber) as cnt,
              row_number() over (partition by c.ConsumerReferenceNumber order by c.ID) as seqnum
       from [dbo].[tbl_NADRA_CPS] c
      )
 update toupdate
    set StatusID = 38
 where cnt > 1 and seqnum = 1;
```

The `cnt > 1` gets reference numbers with more than one row.  The `seqnum = 1` ensures that just one is updated.